# Sitefinity: How do I get the title of a taxonomy "tag" when viewing the page filtered by that tag?

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, sitefinity

If I have clicked a link generated by a Tag widget in Sitefinity, I end up on a page with a URL like this:

`/normal-url/-in-tags/tags/tag-name`

If I have an MVC control on the /normal-url/ page, how can I pull the `tag-name` into a View or into the Controller?

Answer (score 0):

string lastSegment = Request.Url.Segments[Request.Url.Segments.Count()];

I haven't tried this but the theory works since sitefinty is predictable. You can also in the advanced edit of the widget set it to use QueryString instead of URLPath its the UrlEvaluator property. That would allow for easy access to the parameter. But not pretty though :(

Answer (score 0):

I modified what Jon R. posted and this worked for me:

```
string lastSegment = Request.Url.Segments.Last();
```

Comment: Even better would be to use TaxonUrlEvaluator.GetTaxonFromQuery(Request.RequestContext.HttpContext); 
this is in the Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Mvc.Infrastructure.Routing namespace

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TaxonUrlEvaluator.GetTaxonFromQuery(Request.RequestContext.HttpContext);`

from the `Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Mvc.Infrastructure.Routing` namespace.